# My Bootstrap carousel doesnt work when i put my browser in the startup folder

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, carousel, startup

I want my carousel to automatically go to the next slide when the computer starts. It works when I start the browser manually but not when I put it in the startup folder.
I tried to put different browsers in the startup folder (IE11 and latest Chrome) of Windows 7, but that didn't work. 
I also wrote a little script in JS which refreshed the page once after 20 seconds, and i also put a delay on the browser startup with 2 minutes. Thinking that maybe some libraries weren't loaded properly or something. But that also didn't help.

What could cause this problem?

EDIT: https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/carousel/ Here they say that it doesn't slide when there is no page visibility, so maybe at startup the tab is not focused? Is there a way to focus a tab in jQuery or HTML?

```
>   <div id="text-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel"
> data-interval="20000">
>       <div class="row">
>           <div class="col-xs-offset-3 col-xs-6">
>               <div class="carousel-inner">
> 
>                   <div class="item active">
>                       <div class="carousel-content">
>                           <div>
>                               <img src="img/7.jpg">
>                           </div>
>                       </div>
>                   </div>
>                   <div class="item">
>                 `enter code here`      <div class="carousel-content">
>                           <div class="border">
>                               <h1>Hou uw identiteitskaart klaar voor de balie!</h1>                          
>                           </div>
>                       </div>
>                   </div>                                      
>               </div>
>           </div>
>       </div>
>       <a class="left carousel-control" href="#text-carousel" data-slide="prev">
>           <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>      </a>        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#text-carousel"
> data-slide="next">
>           <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>         </a>    </div>
```